# Integrity constraint violation: Column cannot be null Error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Maatwebsite\Excel` to export and store data from an `Excel` file. I'm getting an error: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column delegate_id cannot be null Error` which says that the column can't be `Null`. However I'm affecting a value to `delegate_id` but I'm still getting that error message. Is there something wrong with my code below?

```js
public function model(array $row) {
  $delegate = Delegate::where('email',$row['mail'])->first();
  if (!$delegate) {
    $delegate = new Delegate([
                'name' => $row["name"],
                'phone' => $row["tel"],
                'email' => $row["mail"]]);
  }
  
  $newZipcode = new Zipcode();
  $newDelegateZipcode->zipcode = $row["cp"];

  $data = DB::table('delegates')->latest()->first();

  if ($data === null) {
    $newZipcode->delegate_id = 0;
  } else {
    if ($delegate->id === null) {
      $newZipcode->delegate_id = $data->id + 1;
    } else {
      $newZipcode->delegate_id = $delegate->id;
    }
  }

  $newZipcode->delegate()->associate($delegate);
  $newZipcode->save();
  
  return $delegate;
}
```

Comment: If you never call `$delegate->save()`, then `$delegate->id` is going to be `null` on this line: `$newZipcode->delegate_id = $delegate->id;` Also, if you allow `0` as `delegate_id`, maybe you should allow `null`?

Comment: You never save the delegate, so it has no ID.

Comment: I'm using `Maatwebsite\Excel` to export and store data from an Excel file. if i added `$delegate->save()` inside the model function will not that cause a problem ?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know, why don't you give it a try and see  Either way, if `delegate_id` as a column doesn't allow `null`, you need to ensure that `$delegate->id` is not `null` when you try to use it; that's the core of your issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Tim Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69048240/integrity-constraint-violation-column-cannot-be-null-error#comment122033523_69048240) said, you never call the `save()` method, so the data will not be created, result is `null`.

To insert a new record into the database, you should instantiate a new model instance and set attributes on the model. Then, call the `save()` method on the model instance:

```
$model = new MyModel($input);
$model->save();
```

Just like the `$newZipcode` you applied.

I recommend using the `firstOrCreate()` method, instead of using a condition when the data doesn't exist.

```
$delegate = Delegate::where('email', $row['mail'])
    ->firstOrCreate([
        'name'  => $row['name'],
        'phone' => $row['tel'],
        'email' => $row['mail'],
    ]);

$newZipcode = Zipcode::create([
    'zipcode'     => $row['cp'],
    'delegate_id' => $delegate->id,
]);

// or via relation
```